# Displaying a javascript variable array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a variable array that results in a table filtering depending on the user input. I get the array result in a `console.log` now I want to display it in HTML.

I tried : `document.getElementById("Tableau").innerHTML = res.toString();`

where "res" is the array result, but that only shows elements separated with commas when I want to have a somewhat well presented simple HTML table.

```
var res = station.filter( i => i[0] >= gval1 && i[0] <= gval2 );
document.getElementById("Tableau").innerHTML = res.toString();
console.log(res);
```

This is the HTML table :

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Id </th>
        <th> Station </th>
        <th> Line </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is my javascript table :

```
var station = [
[0,'JAMAA EL FNA','L1'],
[1,'KOUTOUBIA','L1'],
[2,'HOTEL DE VILLE','L1'],
[3,'R.P BERDII','L1'],
[4,'GRAND POSTE','L1'],
[5,'CAREE EDEN','L1'],
[6,'PL ABDELMOUMEN','L1'],
[7,'PLACE D ARMES','L1'],
[8,'FST','L1'],
[9,'SEMIRAMIS','L1'],
[10,'DR KUDIA','L1'],
[11,'MCDO','L1'],
[12,'CAFE AMINE','L1'],
[13,'FAC SEMLALIA','L1'],
[14,'ROUIDATE','L1'],
[15,'CLUB MINISTRE JUSTICE','L1'],
[16,'BEN TBIB','L1'],
[17,'ASWAK SALAM','L1'],
[18,'BAB DOUKALA','L1'],
[19,'JAMAA EL FNA','L2'],
[20,'KOUTOUBIA','L2'],
[21,'PH KOUTOUBIA','L2'],
[22,'RIAD SHEBA','L2'],
[23,'DAR LBACHA','L2'],
[24,'RIAD LAAROUSSE','L2'],
[25,'BAB TAGHZOUT','L2'],
[26,'BIN LMAASAR','L2'],
[27,'ARSET EL MELLAK','L2'],
[28,'HOPITAL ANTAKI','L2'],
[29,'AVENUE ANTAKI','L2'],
[30,'QCHICH','L2'],
[31,'RUE BAB KHACHICH','L2'],
[32,'AIN ITTI','L2']];
```

How can I loop through the array to display it on the table?

Comment: use `res.join()` instead of `res.toString()`

Comment: You can loop trought the array and display it on the table

Comment: Can you provide the html code for the table

Answer (score 3):

use [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to construct your `html` and put the array elements in `td` tags :

```js
const res = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const cells = '<tr><td>' + res.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>' ;
document.getElementById("Tableau").innerHTML = cells;
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="Tableau">

</table>
```

**EDIT :** 
based on the edited question, you'll need a loop to go through the array eleemnts and wrap each line in a `<tr>` and append the result to the `<tbody>`, use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this :

```js
var station = [
  [0, 'JAMAA EL FNA', 'L1'],
  [1, 'KOUTOUBIA', 'L1'],
  [2, 'HOTEL DE VILLE', 'L1'],
  [3, 'R.P BERDII', 'L1']
]

var rows = station.map(e => {
  return '<tr><td>' + e.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>';
})

document.getElementById("tBody").innerHTML = rows.join(' ');
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="Tableau">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Id </th>
      <th> Station </th>
      <th> Line </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you it's working, how can I separate the elements (id,station and line) into rows and make the list go vertically instead of horizontally ?

Comment: i can't tell how you can seperate them without seeing the array you're working with

Answer (score 0):

### Rendering HTML with JavaScript is fun

Since you have a list and you need to make the delimiter table like, I would suggest inserting a `<br />` tag between table items. Like so:

```
Tableau.innerHTML = res.join('<br />')
```

Answer (score 0):

As Taki mentioned you can use  `res.join()`  to covert array into a string.

Speaking about styling it, may be the following would help.

Assuming you have an array as follows,

```
var statements=['1st statement','2nd statement','3rd statement','4th statement','5th statement'];
    console.log(statements.join('-'));
```

would yield the following

```
1st statement-2nd statement-3rd statement-4th statement-5th statement
```

and say you do the following

```
var styledRes ='<tr class="your-class-name"><td>' + statements.join('</td><td>')+' </td></tr>'
```

would yield

```
<tr class="your-class-name">
 <td>1st statement</td>
 <td>2nd statement</td>
 <td>3rd statement</td>
 <td>4th statement</td>
 <td>5th statement</td>
</tr>
```

And you can do your style definitions in your css file and they will get applied here.

When you do

```
document.getElementById("Tableau").innerHTML = styledRes;
```

you would see something like the following on screen

```
<table>
   <tr class="your-class-name">
     <td>1st statement</td>
     <td>2nd statement</td>
     <td>3rd statement</td>
     <td>4th statement</td>
     <td>5th statement</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And assume you have styles defined as follows,

```
.your-class-name td{
```

border:2px solid green;
}

you would be able to see something like the following on screen

```css
.your-class-name td{
 border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table>
       <tr class="your-class-name">
         <td>1st statement</td>
         <td>2nd statement</td>
         <td>3rd statement</td>
         <td>4th statement</td>
         <td>5th statement</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Is this what you are looking for?